# Entity Model Relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have the database and there are 4 tables in it named City, Course, College, Student. When I create the ADO.NET Entity Data Model, it is not showing the foreign key column relationships but in the database it is exist.

My Entity Model Screenshot:

[image]

The Student table have four keys in the database:

[image]

How can I show the full Entity Model with all relationships?

Comment: Delete the tables from edmx and add 'em again.

Comment: I have done it Mr.@AmarDuplantier. Nothing happen

Comment: You can't see them in Model Browser under Associations?

Comment: The diagram does not show the relationship. like one to one , one to many @AmarDuplantier

Comment: That 1-----* is one to many in your diagram.

Comment: Yes but where are the others? @AmarDuplantier

Comment: You can see in my Object browser for further keys in the Student table..@AmarDuplantier

Comment: So you can find the relationships under Associations in Model Browser?  I am not sure why it's not displayed in the diagram.